# Sockets in C: consecutive order of primitive calls

Tags: c, sockets

I've written basic server in C. The source code of the server is something like this:

```
int sfd;
...
read(sfd,...);
write(sfd,...);
...
```

and the client is:

```
int sfd;
...
write(sfd,...);
read(sfd,...);
...
```

What is the order in which those primitives are called? `write(client), read(server), write(server), read(client)`. In this order? If not, is there a way we can ensure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` and `read` are blocking. It doesn't matter which is called first. If you call `read` on the server before `write` on the client, then `read` will block until receives the appropriate number of bytes.

Comment: Is it possible for write, read on the client to be both executed before read on the server then?

Comment: Yes. Although the `read` on the client will block until the server has finished `write`.

Comment: What I meant was is it possible for the client to read something that he just written (write and read on the client are executed consecutively before read on the server)?

Comment: `read` on a socket will not read what you write, it's reads what was written at the other end of the socket.

Comment: So, actually there are two buffers - one for the pair `(read(client), write(server))` and one for `(read(server), write(client))`?

Comment: Each socket has two buffers. One for receiving, and one for sending. So four. Of course, depending on the type of socket, there will likely be additional buffering by the network hardware or other components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure a specific order you need to use a mutex or some other concurrency tool (semaphore, etc).

Unless there's more to your application than you're showing, you probably don't care about the order -- read() will block until its corresponding write() has been performed, unless you set a non-blocking option.

Comment: Mutexes and semaphores of course will only work if the client and server are running on the same machine.